# checkbox text not getting displayed on textview

Tags: android

I am new to android technology, i wanted the checkbox's text to be displayed using textview.
I think the problem is in TextUtils.join function
For e.g 
If my checklist is a, b, c, d.

I want to display the textview like

//Text view string
you have selected a, b, c, d.

Code Snippet :

```
public class Menu3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    CheckBox checkBox2;
    CheckBox checkBox3;
    CheckBox checkBox4;

    TextView tView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu3);

        checkBox  = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        checkBox4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

        tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        checkBox2.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        checkBox3.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        checkBox4.setOnClickListener(ocl);

        String all = TextUtils.join(",", arrayList);

        tView.setText(all);
    }

    View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            if(checked) {
                String text = null;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.checkBox:
                        text = checkBox.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(Menu3.this, text + " checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arrayList.add(text);
                        break;

                    case R.id.checkBox2:
                        text = checkBox2.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(Menu3.this, text + " checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arrayList.add(text);
                        break;

                    case R.id.checkBox3:
                        text = checkBox3.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(Menu3.this, text + " checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arrayList.add(text);
                        break;

                    case R.id.checkBox4:
                        text = checkBox4.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(Menu3.this, text + " checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arrayList.add(text);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setText` right away in `onCreate`, and it isn't called again when the checkboxes are changed. Personally, I'd set up a method that gets called when a checkbox is changed to handle all of this

Something like this

```
private void updateTextView(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(Menu3.this, text + " checked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    arrayList.add(text);
    String all = TextUtils.join(",", arrayList);
    tView.setText(all);
}
```

Then call it from all of your `OnClickListener` for the checkboxes

```
case R.id.checkBox:
    updateTextView(checkBox.getText().toString());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text first, after then, you are not setting anything. You must set text every time you add/remove string to your arraylist.

Comment: first onclicklistener is activated, i have made onclicklistener outside the oncreate method

Comment: You must update every time you check any checkbox. I doesn't matter your clicklistener is inside or outside of your onCreate method. onCreate only called one time.